# Optimising filtering multiple SQL count sub queries with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert raw postgres-SQL into sqlalchemy which uses a count and filter

```
SELECT

  (
   SELECT
     COUNT(user_model.uuid)
     FILTER ( WHERE  email_vector @@ parse_websearch('search term'))
   ) AS email_vector,

   (
    SELECT
    COUNT(user_model.uuid)
    FILTER ( WHERE  first_name_vector @@ parse_websearch('search term'))
    ) AS first_name_vector,

FROM 
user_model

WHERE  
(user_model.uuid = '20d7c90d-ebfa-4b04-9ee7-4fdedabc6c0b' AND all_vectors @@  parse_websearch('search term')  )
```

This works great and is very fast (sub 100ms - even when filtering 20 fields)

I've written the sqlalchemy as (simplified)

```
search_query = []
search_vectors = [ email_vector, first_name_vector]
search_vector_names = [ 'email_vector', 'first_name_vector' ] 

for search_vector, search_vector_name in zip(search_vectors, search_vector_names):
     search_query.append(sa.sql.select(
                sa.func.count(user_model.uuid)) \
                    .filter(search_vector.op('@@') \
                        (sa.func.parse_websearch(search_term))) \
                    .label(search_vector_name)
            )

base_query = db.session.query(*search_query)

base_query = base_query.filter(user_model.uuid==user_uuid)
base_query = query.filter(search_vector.op('@@')(sa.func.parse_websearch(search_term))
```

This produces the following SQL

```
SELECT (
  SELECT count(user_model.uuid) AS count_1
  FROM user_model
  WHERE user_model.email_vector @@ parse_websearch(%(parse_websearch_1)s)) AS email_vector, 

  (SELECT count(user_model.uuid) AS count_2
  FROM user_model
  WHERE user_model.first_name_vector @@ parse_websearch(%(parse_websearch_2)s)) AS first_name_vector,
  
WHERE user_model.uuid = %(uuid_1)s AND (user_model.all_vectors @@ parse_websearch(%(parse_websearch_30)s))
```

This works but is quite slow (+1 second). I'm not sure why it's so slow or how to do a filter query on the sub queries.

I suspect the COUNT is being performed on each sub query where the SQL uses the filtered results from the final WHERE condition, but I'm not totally sure and I can't find any reference to filter (which I think it shorthand for CASE?) in the sqlalchemy docs. I've tried adding `.filter(user_model.uuid==uuid)`  to the COUNT SQL but it is still slow.

Would anyone be able to offer an insight into what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did this using CASE

```
            case_stmt = sa.case(
                [
                    (
                        full_text_search_vector.op('@@') \
                        (sa.func.parse_websearch(last_search_term)),1
                    )
                ]
            ).label(col_name)

            query.append(case_stmt)


        base_query = db.session.query(*query)
```